# mkdir in Matlab on sshfs mounted network drive permission denied

Tags: mount, permissions, xubuntu, matlab

I'm trying to make and remove some files and folders as part of a MatLab script I'm developing under Xubuntu 15.04. The script as well as the files and folders are on an sshfs mounted network drive. In the terminal, I can make, edit and delete folders without any trouble, but when I try in MatLab I get a permission denied error.

Now I am relatively new to linux, and my best guess would be that in the terminal the server somehow recognizes my serverspecific user, while matlab is run as local user and that that conflict means I have no permissions to write stuff?

No idea whether that is true though, any insights are appreciated!

Thanks,
Narameh

Edit; 
After logging in via SSH and manually creating the folders all other files and folders should be in, and giving anyone permissions to read and write (in) those folders the rest of the files and folders get created without difficulty. However, I would still like a more direct way of doing this via MatLab if anyone has any inspiration:)!

Answer (score 0):

This questions is quite old. However, the solution that worked for me is to mount the folder using CIFS instead. See instructions below on how to set it up (adopted from https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/)

Installing CIFS utilities on Ubuntu and Debian:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Create a directory to serve as mounting point:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/win_share
```

Create a credential file at for instance `/etc/.win-credentials` containing the following:

```
username=user
password=password
domain=domain
```

Set correct permissions and ownership by running:

```
sudo chown root: /etc/.win_credentials
sudo chmod 600 /etc/.win_credentials
```

Mount the drive with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/.win-credentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share
```

I want to especially highlight the use of the options `dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777` to have full access on files and directories!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287503)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post accordingly.